# jQuery .click function is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javaScript file in which i am trying to bind a function named change by using jQuery i tried this code but it is not working?

```
 script.js

 for(var i=1; i<suggestionList.length; i++)
            {
                $list.append("<li>" + suggestionList[i] + "</li>");
                // attach handler for click on the suggestions
                $list.find("li").eq(i).click(function() {
                    change(suggestionList[0], suggestionList[i]);
                });
            }


    function change(changeto,changewith)
        {
            var replaceto=document.getElementById(changeto).innerHTML;
            var replacewith=changewith;
            var text1=document.getElementById("para").innerHTML;
            var afterRe=text1.replace(replaceto,replacewith);
            document.getElementById("para").innerHTML=afterRe;
        }
```

please help me why my code is not working?

Comment: can you set a fiddle ??

Comment: can you send me the links of which u are talking about

Comment: check my answer if it solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use `i` inside the for-loop for `click` event. I have set a demo jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gwph7776/1/)  .check If it helps

```
for(var i=1; i<suggestionList.length; i++)
{
    $list.append("<li>" + suggestionList[i] + "</li>");
     // attach handler for click on the suggestions

}

$list.find("li").click(function() {
    changewith=$(this).html();
    change(suggestionList[0], changewith);
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ set your code here .

Comment: actually some server connectivity is there so fiddle can not help

Comment: check your console is there any error??

Comment: i checked it there is no error even i debugged the code

Comment: can u tell another way of doing this if it isnot working?

Comment: what is the purpose of this ??

Comment: i m making an spellchecker where i have a list of words as suggestions n i want if i click on one of the suggestion it will replace with the wrong word

Comment: that's what i am trying to do

Comment: are  you getting me?

Comment: may be now looking on the above code u will get it

Comment: comment your function where you are calling . and alert there . i think it is not getting the selection .` $list.find("li").eq(i).click(function() {
                    change(suggestionList[0], suggestionList[i]);
                });`

Comment: is there any link available??

Comment: hey what is this li?

Comment: ok sorry wrong question

Comment: can you show the link ??

Comment: no i cant but i can share my code

Comment: check the updated code . and also the link you need to change in function .

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gwph7776/1/ updated

Comment: let me now if it worked.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gwph7776/3/ this will work